# DomainDataSourceView MoveCurrentTo... keeps looping

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

When

DomainDataSourceView.MoveCurrentToNext()

and

DomainDataSourceView.MoveCurrentToPrevious()

are called several times in a non specific order the DomainDataSourceView gets caught in some sort of loop where the CurrentItem changes to a random item from the collection constantly.
The only way to stop is to close the Silverlight application. 
Is this a known issue?

This is the order of calls in the silverlight mvvm application:

- Button is clicked
- The RelayCommand bound to the button fires a canexecute method (returns true)
- the method for the command is executed and calls DataView.MoveCurrentToNext()
- The RaiseCanExecuteChanged method is called for the first - back -
  next - last button Commands (all return false)
- the CurrentEntity Property on the viewmodel is changed to the current
  item from the domain data source
- Some data is loaded asynchonously for the current entity

When the next button is quickly clicked on several times it starts looping.
When the interval between clicks is somewhat bigger, no issue.

It almost seams like MoveCurrentToNext executes again while it's still processing the first click.
When debugging with breakpoints this never happens. Breakpoints added in all the methods
while looping never get hit.
Has anyone got an idea how to fix this or what might cause this?

Comment: It's impossible to tell because we don't have the source code for *any* of the events that are occuring, but if you're dealing with a race condition (and it seems you may), you'll have to handle it like any other race condition. That is, you're going to have to stop things from happening to ensure it can't be hit (e.g. disable the button from being clicked until the chain of events is done). I had to do this **a lot** in Silverlight.

Comment: It seems to be a race condition indeed, it's impossible to find the exact problem since it doesn't happen when I add breakpoints. When a breakpoint is hit Silverlight doesn't respond so i cannot quickly hit any other buttons.

Comment: What I had to do, ***a lot***, was chain events and disable parts of the UX while that was happening. Then when the chain was over I enabled everything again. It's because Silverlight is fully asynchronous.

Comment: Hmm I will take a look at it and make sure everything is disabled when it should be.

Comment: You comment led me to the real issue, the MoveCurrentTo.... methods are all asynchronous and when multiple are called within milliseconds, you cannot be sure which one will finish last. One of those calls was in an if statement right before another, which caused them to be called almost simultaneously.
Working on a fix right now and it look promising tnx.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.